# Hiding AppBarLayout on RecyclerView Scroll using MaterialDesignComponents

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, material-components-android

I'm trying to collapse the AppBarLayout when I scroll up the RecyclerView. I'm trying this using Material Design Components.

So here's my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/component_recycler_view"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:contentDescription="@string/extended_fab_content_desc"
        android:text="@string/extended_fab_label"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_plus_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/component_recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/component_recycler_view"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I scroll up on the recyclerview, it does scroll up but the appbarlayout does not hide itself. Moreover the topmost item of the RecyclerView is partially hidden behind the AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout) to achieve a [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout), something like this:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:title="@string/choose_hero">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am using this type of layout and my app bar is collapsing/expanding without hiding any recyclerView items.

Comment: What if I don't want an ImageView? Will it still work?

Comment: I dont see any reason not to, try using the code without imageview/another view that you want and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Well thats the thing. I only want the Toolbar with the app name written in it. And below it the recyclerview. When the recyclerview scrolls up, the appbarlayout should also scroll up

Comment: What about bot using any view at all? Can you try this?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer. A bit modifications to your code, and I've got what I needed :)